# How do i increase the volume of a video I recorded?

Tags: mp4

I shot a .mp4 video from my cellphone. Turns out that the volume is very low. How can I increase it?

Comment: What software do you have, if any?  There are literally hundreds of ways you could accomplish this, though the quality is likely to not be great as there will probably be a lot of noise relative to the sound you want.

Comment: Consider me illiterate on this. I've no software for this job. Kindly let me know one.

Comment: What OS does your computer have?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ffmpeg`:

```
    ffmpeg -i file_with_quiet_sound.mp4 -af volume=150 -vcodec copy newfile.mp4
```

It will increase volume of your file at 150 times! Don't worry, big values can do funny effects, I like it. But I think, you will get many noises and not will love result.

If you want really make sound better, convert your video to `.wav` file with ffmpeg:

```
    ffmpeg -i file_with_quiet_sound.mp4 sound.wav
```

And then open it in any audio editor. I can suggest Audacity, this is free software with good features. I like old version 2.0.2 where exists old version of "Noise remove" filters which can produce magic with your sound (if you can do it right). If you don't like Audacity, you can to use any other audio editor. When editing of sound is done, you can join video and audio:

```
    ffmpeg -i file_with_quiet_sound.mp4 -i fixed_sound.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy newfile.mp4
```

Pretty simple. All software is free and available on every platform.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and would have taken me forever to figure out. Thank you! I love stackexchange :)